# Google drive edit link for not logged in users

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need to share files with others so that they can see and edit my google docs without logging into google.

I created correctly permissions for writing for "anyone with the link", and I can only view that file as not logged into google because I don't have an edit button, that button is only visible for logged-in users.
For the spreadsheet I resolved this problem, because the edit link is always the same, with `google-file-id` like this: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/`**{33_character_google_id}**`/edit`

But for other files, the edit link looks like this: `https://docs.google.com/document/d/`{**44_character_hash**}`/edit`

I have no idea where this hash is coming from

Is it possible to prepare that hash or get him from API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was more complicated than I thought.
I didn't get webLink from `DriveFile` in response after upload, and also I was getting an object with `webViewLink` only for read after download - I don't know for what reason.

But the solution was to download `webViewLink` by this one line of code:

```
$this->googleServiceDrive->files->get($googleId, ['fields' => 'webViewLink'])
```

(BTW I have read somewhere that webViewLink stores edit link if edition is possible by google editor, and stores read link if not).